# Get data from lines() function

Tags: r, plot, lines, smoothing

I have a plot like this (black points): [image]
I calculate the average of some points (smoothing - the red points in the plot).
Then I can draw with the lines() function a line between these points (blue in the plot). What I want now is the data of the blue line.

Does somebody know how to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: The blue line is drawn between the red points, no? So shouldn't the data of the blue line be the red points?

Comment: Yes, the line is drawn between the red points. I want basically a higher resolution, i.e. more points between the red points.

Comment: What do you mean by more points between red points. Correct me please, but red points are calculated ones, so how can you have more points

Comment: Higher resolution - did you try xlim? the data after 5000 is 0

Comment: Like have points on the blue line.

Comment: I have solved it with the approx. function.

Comment: It would have been easier to solve if you had known that this is called *interpolation*.

Comment: I was so fixed on trying to get the data from the lines() function that I didn't think in any other direction. Still don't get why I can't get the data from the lines() function.

Comment: Of course you're right and this is embarrassing.

Comment: `lines` only connects points. Since internally this is a vector graphics operation, there is no data of points between start and end point involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `approx` function which interpolates between points:

```
approx(x = r, y = ionizations, n = 1000)
```

[image]